# Resize Jframe using external frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

What I have done is created a form that has a table displaying inventory. When an item is right clicked, a popup menu is shown where the user can click edit inventory edit (JFrame will resize to (988, 736)). A Panel will be loaded from an external class with buttons and labels.  What I am trying to achieve here is when the user clicks save, a hidden "Close" button becomes visible. Once the close button is clicked then the panel will be set invisible and what I also need it to do is set the JFrame back to its original size (988, 430). How do I go about achieving this (Setting the JFrame back to (988, 430) from the External Class)?

Here is the code I have for it so far:

On this event button below i would like to insert the coding to resize the JFrame. This coding is in the class (SV2.java)

```
 private void btn_closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
   {
      SV1 objc = new SV1();
       Panel.setVisible(false);
       objc.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(988,430));
       objc.getContentPane().setSize(new Dimension(988, 430));

       // coding to resize JFrame in class SV1.java, from setting it within this class

   }
```

Comment: You could pass the JFrame to the panel object in the constructor

Comment: I have already tried to pass it through the constructor. can us just provide a brief example just for clarity. In case I am just forgetting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SV2.java:

```
//Add instance variable for parent
private JFrame parent;

//Add JFrame to the constructor
public SV2(SomeType someParameter, OtherType foo, JFrame parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    //rest of constructor code...
}

//Use JFrame to resize
private void btn_closeActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    parent.setSize(988, 430);
    //rest of code triggered by close button...
}
```

In the class that calls the panel:

```
//Pass the frame when instantiating the SV2 object
new SV2(yourParameter1, yourOtherParameter, frame);
```